# Monitor Cursor Position system wide

Tags: c#, cursor, monitoring

I need to make a small system tray app which monitors the cursor position systemwide and displays or hides the onscreen keyboard depending on the cursor handle ID. if the cursor is in a textbox (position equals IBeam) in IE,for example, the keyboard pops up.
I have code for the the system tray app (formless app) but cannot find a way of making it monitor the system. Any help with a function to monitor the system for cursor position would be welcome. thanks.

Comment: It can be done easily with standard `TextBox`, but it's not easy with some kind of composited `TextBox` such as `TextBox` in `WPF`.

Comment: Just use Cursor.Position in a timer's Tick event handler.

Comment: a sample code, please?

Answer (score 0):

To be event-driven you'll need to use `SetWindowsHookEx`.  You cannot do it directly through .NET, but must inject a DLL.  Here is a [MSDN article on making a mouse hook](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804).  This is done using `System.Runtime.InteropServices` to import user32.dll.  The MSDN article gives step-by-step instructions on calling `SetWindowsHookEx`,  `CallNextHookEx`, and `UnhookWindowsHookEx` from C#.  CodeProject also has an article on [making system-wide hooks in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6362/Global-System-Hooks-in-NET).

Comment: I don't think you want to look at the cursor handle, but rather do a hit test on the mouse position.  Look at this [SO post about WindowFromPoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901183/how-can-i-tell-if-the-mouse-is-over-a-top-level-window).

Comment: found a guy looking for the same thing in C++. Anybody to convert the code to c#? I did use a converter but not sure it does all the necessary conversion stuff : LRESULT CALLBACK winProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
if (nCode < 0)
return CallNextHookEx(hhk, nCode, wParam, lParam);

if (lParam)
{
CWPSTRUCT * msg = (CWPSTRUCT *) lParam;
if ((msg->message == WM_COMMAND) && (HIWORD(msg->wParam) == EN_SETFOCUS))
MessageBox(NULL, "focus !", "Information", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}

return CallNextHookEx(hhk, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

Comment: @JoeCoder take a look at the MSDN article that I mentioned.  It shows how to call these functions from C#.

Answer (score 0):

Monitor the system cursor position:

```
            private void Pos()
            {
                for (; ; )
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                    Point position = Cursor.Position;
//You can use these to pass to your system tray or whereever you need it.
                    somePublicXVar = position.X; 
                    somePublicYVar = position.Y; 
                }

            }
            public void PointPosition()
            {
                Thread pointThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Pos));
                pointThread.Start();
            }
```

Comment: The loop takes a lot of CPU !!

Comment: Depending on your needs you should try using a higher number for Thread.Sleep(MinMilisecondsYouCanAfford). Hope it helps.

Comment: the need is: whenever my cursor is positioned in a textbook in any application the onscreen keyboard sould come up like on tablets. Windows Metro does perfectly but desktop mode lacks this feature.

Comment: @Regu or set a tick event like Hans Passant commented on the original post.

Comment: re-used the code with a condition and the cursor.position. if I use the .Position the position changes with mouse move but if I want cursor.handle the handle does not change.